# How can I influence Hibernate’s naming schema for table aliases?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, kotlin

After updating to Hibernate 6, the behaviour for creating table aliases seems to have changed. The result is an Oracle error “ORA-00911: invalid character” because some identifiers start with underscores.

A bit of context: Using Kotlin, we want to access some field of entities in a safe way, but Hibernate needs full access. So, we specified a *public* field `volumesPerHour` for clients, and a *private* field `_volumesPerHour` for Hibernate’s use. However, these names are used to create some identifiers; an example for an entity `Shift`:

```sql
/* select s._volumesPerHour from Shift s where s.id = "1234-5678" */
select _1_0.id,… from shift s1_0 join volumes_per_hour _1_0 on s1_0.id=_1_0.shift_id where s1_0.id='1234-5678'
```

To refer to the tables `shift` and `volumes_per_hour`, Hibernate creates table aliases `s1_0` and `_1_0`. One seems to be derived from the table name, the other from the *field name* instead. Since a leading underscore is illegal in Oracle, this breaks the queries.

The naming schema was different in Hibernate 5, yielding `shift0_` and `volumespe0_`. Now, using `org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect` instead of `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect` (because the latter is deprecated) Hibernate breaks Oracle. What can I do to prevent it?

Answer (score -1):

If you have identifiers starting with underscores then, in Oracle, you must use double-quoted identifiers.

In hibernate, there is an option [`hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52333007/1509264) which you can set to `true` which will wrap all identifiers in double quotes.

Comment: This breaks a lot of things, since now oracle will look for a table called _exactly_ `shift`, which does not exist (it would be found under the name of `SHIFT`).

And anyway, it is not _my_ identifier in the SQL that starts with an underscore, it’s an identifier that Hibernate generated. And used to generate differently.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this one? I have the same issue.

Comment: Okay, I found the reason in my case. I had a property for class with a name that started with underscore. Hibernate generated the alias for that field with as underscore. It looks like this (very old) issue HHH-2022 is happening again.

I will log a new issue for this one. In the meantime, I renamed my field names and all is well.

Comment: Logged HHH-17447 https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-17447 for this one.